# How to debug playbook simulator?

Tags: android, debugging, blackberry, simulator, blackberry-playbook

I've converted my Android app to a playbook bar; it works (with a lot of graphical bugs); however I'd like to know if it is possible to debug the software while it's running.

Of course, I don't ask for the "luxury" of an adb equivalent, but at the very least, I'd like to get some printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard

```
Log.d("Tag", "Message text");
```

logging methods and watch the info in LogCat, as well as set a breakpoint and start debugging in Eclipse.
I just verified it, the breakpoint was hit.