# Quick way to develop, debug and run android apps on Blackberry Playbook running Playbook OS 2.0

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook

Has anyone come up with a strategy for quickly debugging and running android apps on Blackberry Playbook running Playbook OS 2.0 using the eclipse plug-in and command-line scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug playbook simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329830/how-to-debug-playbook-simulator)

Comment: Actually I'm trying to debug directly on the device in Development Mode and not using the playbook simulator.

Comment: Well, have you tried to actually debug the way I described? Do you get any error?

Comment: I've tried the simulator but I'm trying to use the device instead of the simulator since the simulator runs slow.

Comment: I used the simulator installation instructions here -

Comment: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/documentation/install_plugin_prerequisites_1895476_11.html

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

- Make sure Android project targets 2.3.3 SDK,
- Install the Blackberry plug-in for ADT (it sounds like you've already
  done this),
- From the Blackberry Tools menu, select "add blackberry nature to
  project",
- Put your Playbook into dev mode (see the security section of the
  settings),
- Install a debug token into your Playbook (see the 'BAR Signer' page
  of Eclipse preferences).

Now you can run and debug apps on your playbook pretty much the same way you would on a regular Android device.  In the `run as` and `debug as` Eclipse menus you should find options for running your app on a Blackberry.  If not, go into `run configurations` and create something under the 'blackberry android application' group.

You mention command-line scripts, but there is no need for that.

Comment: Regarding the first point: the project should target SDK 2.3.3 _or earlier_.